# Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Why am i getting this error **Cannot read property touched of undefined**?

Why is it not able to read `formName.controls['email'].touched` but its able to read `formName.get('custDetails').touched`

```
<form [formGroup]="formName">
<fieldset formGroupName="custdetails">
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': formName.controls['email'].touched 
                && formName.controls['email'].hasError('invalidEmailAddress')}">
        <label class="control-label">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                formControlName="email" name="email" required />
    </div>
</fieldset>        

</form>
```

When we use `formName.get('custdetails.email').touched` ... i get the below erro

> TypeError: _this.subscribe is not a function
>       at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.js:68:15)
>       at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:551:29)
>       at Object.toPromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.js:66:12)
>       at _convertToPromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms//bundles/forms.umd.js:541:73)
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at FormControl.eval [as asyncValidator] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms//bundles/forms.umd.js:530:101)
>       at FormControl.AbstractControl._runAsyncValidator (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms//bundles/forms.umd.js:2670:62)
>       at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms//bundles/forms.umd.js:2630:26)
>       at FormControl.setValue (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms//bundles/forms.umd.js:2988:18)
>       at DefaultValueAccessor.eval [as onChange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/forms//bundles/forms.umd.js:1658:21)
>       at Wrapper_DefaultValueAccessor.handleEvent (/InternalFormsSharedModule/DefaultValueAccessor/wrapper.ngfactory.js:29:34)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ReactiveFormComponentFive0.handleEvent_36
>   (/AppModule/ReactiveFormComponentFive/component.ngfactory.js:717:45)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:12397:41)
>       at HTMLInputElement.eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser//bundles/platform-browser.umd.js:3224:57)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:275:35)

Below is how my form is construct:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.formName = this.fb.group({
       name: ["", [Validators.required]], 
       custdetails: this.fb.group({
            email: ["", Validators.required, ValidationHelper.emailValidator],
            confirm: ["", Validators.required]
        }, {
            validator: ValidationHelper.emailMatcher
        })

    })
}
```

And my email validator:

```
static emailValidator = (control: AbstractControl) : {[key: string]: boolean} =>{
        // RFC 2822 compliant regex
        if (control.value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return { 'invalidEmailAddress': true };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The complete path to the field is:

```
formName.get('custdetails.email')
```

So you need to access:

```
formName.get('custdetails.email').touched
```

Also, you have an error in the form model. When multiple validators are applied to the same field, they should be wrapped inside an array:

```ts
// Replace that:
email: ["", Validators.required, ValidationHelper.emailValidator]
// With this:
// Notice the additional [ ] around the validators
email: ["", [Validators.required, ValidationHelper.emailValidator]]
```

By passing the two validators as separate parameters, Angular interprets the second validator `emailValidator` as an **async validator** and it tries to subscribe to it. Hence the error message "_this.subscribe is not a function".

Comment: I get an error.... TypeError: _this.subscribe is not a function... check my updated post

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the form model declaration. Can you show the code for the form **model** (i.e. what you have in your class)?

Comment: You have an error where you declare the validators. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

add in TS file

`get email(){ return this.formName.get('custdetails.email'); }`

add validation in html

`*ngIf="email.touched"`