# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (in P5js / p5.play.js)

Tags: javascript, p5.js, p5.play

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'touches')
        at p5._main.default._updateTouchCoords (p5.js:78864)
        at p5._updateNextTouchCoords (p5.play.js:265)
        at p5._onmousedown (p5.play.js:302)
```

I am getting this error in my console!
IDK how to fix this

i guess thats a problem in that library

im using p5.js along with p5.play.js
There is no problem in my code ,
in fact . All my projects with these 2 libraries have the problem

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249764/cannot-read-property-touched-of-undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/molleindustria/p5.play/issues/206) with the latest release of p5.play. Fortunately it shouldn't generally interfere with the basic functionality of the library. However, this library is not well maintained I recommend against using it.